# Set variable to change on next line in given file during loop python

Tags: python

Here im workin on a script which will go through and analyze all given .mp3 files in a .txt document which will contain the full path to the files. Then it prints out the metadata along with the file path. This analyzing will run in a loop until all lines in the document have been read. I can do this individually if I manually specify the location of the file, but unable to do so when make the variable change per new line in the document when looped. I have tried putting all these functions under 1 large function and looping it but then I still get an undefined variable for "song". Do note: I am a complete noob at python and this is my first attempt at building this small project.

The goal: loop function that goes through every line of .txt and sets that line of text as the "song" variable for the destination that the analyzer function can then go read & print.

Here is the code which works when the file location is manually set:

```
    song = "Z:/Vibe Playlists\Throwbacks\Taio Cruz - Hangover ft. Flo Rida.mp3"
    audio1 = ID3(song) #artist,album,title,bpm,initial key,date,
    audio2 = MP3(song) #length
    audio3 = eyed3.load(song) #publisher
    audio4 = mp3.Mp3AudioFile(song) #bitrate
    ###########################
    #global variables for JSON#
    ###########################
    artist = ""
    title = ""
    album = ""
    genre = ""
    bpm = ""
    initial_key = ""
    date = ""
    length = ""
    publisher = ""
    bitrate = ""
    song_location = song
    ###############################
    def analyze_metadata():   
        try:
                Artist = audio1['TPE1'].text[0]
    #            print("Artist:",Artist) #Artist
                global artist 
                artist = Artist
        except KeyError:
    #        print("no artist") - Debugging
            pass
        try:
            Title =audio1['TIT2'].text[0]
            global title
            title = Title             
    #            print("Title:",audio1['TIT2'].text[0]) #title
        except KeyError:
    #        print("no title") - Debugging
            pass 
        try:
            Album = audio1['TALB'].text[0]
            global album
            album = Album
    #            print("Album:",audio1['TALB'].text[0]) #album
        except KeyError:
    #        print("no album") - Debugging
            pass
        try:
            Genre = audio3.tag.genre.name
            global genre
            genre = Genre
    #            print("Genre:",audio3.tag.genre.name) #genre
        except AttributeError:
    #        print("no genre") - Debugging
            pass  
        try:
            Bpm = audio1['TBPM'].text[0]
            global bpm
            bpm = Bpm    
    #            print("BPM:",audio1['TBPM'].text[0]) #bpm
        except KeyError:
    #        print("no bpm") - Debugging
            pass
        try:        
            Initial_Key = audio1['TKEY'].text[0]
            global initial_key
            initial_key = Initial_Key
    #            print("Initial Key:",audio1['TKEY'].text[0]) #initial key
        except KeyError:
    #        print("no key") - Debugging
            pass
        try:        
            Date = audio1['TDRC'].text[0]
            global date
            date = Date
    #            print("Date:",audio1['TDRC'].text[0]) #date/year
        except KeyError:
    #        print("no date") - Debugging
            pass
    
        song_length = (audio2.info.length) #length
        def convert(seconds):
            return time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(song_length))
    #    print("Length",convert(song_length))
        global length
        length = time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(song_length))
    
        Publisher = audio3.tag.publisher
    #    print("Publisher:",audio3.tag.publisher) #publisher
        global publisher
        publisher = Publisher
    
        song_bitrate = str(audio4.info.bit_rate)
        song_bitrate = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', song_bitrate)
    #    print("Bit rate:",song_bitrate, "kbps") #bitrate
        global bitrate
        bitrate = song_bitrate
    #to call function u do this#
    analyze_metadata()
    #testing global variables for json
    def Print_Metadata():
        print("Artist:",artist)
        print("Title:",title)
        print("Album:",album)
        print("Genre:",genre)
        print("BPM:",bpm)
        print("Initial Key:",initial_key)
        print("Date:",date)
        print("Length:",length)
        print("Publisher:",publisher)
        print("Bitrate:",bitrate)
        print("Location:", song_location)
    Print_Metadata()
```

This prints the metadata to shell, but when I try to run the same code within a while loop that changes the "song" variable to the location of the second line and then third and so on, I get an undefined error.

```
def make_filepath_variable():
filepath = 'py_test.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    cnt = 1
    while line:
        #print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
        line = fp.readline()
        cnt += 1
        global song
        song = line
        print(song)
make_filepath_variable()
```

when this code is run before all other functions, The rest of the above code cant grab the variable information. although from this code i can print every line of the text and go down one by one.
I've been going through forums for almost 2 days now trying to find a way to do this and i'm unable to find anything similar or usable that works in my situation.. Some insight or tips would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Which parts of the last snippet are part of the `make_filepath_variable()` function?

Comment: `fp.readline()` returns a line that ends with newline. You probably need to remove that with `line = line.strip()`

Comment: The normal way to iterate through a file is `for line in fp:`

Comment: What's the relationship between the loop that reads from the file and the code you posted at the top?

Comment: Put that code in a function that takes `song` as a parameter. Then call the function from your loop.

Comment: Learn to use function parameters, not global variables.

Comment: sorry, ive edited the indentations. The relationship between the original code and the last snippet is the top code relies on the bottom snippet to get a new file location to then analyze the new file when run. I'll try what you suggested!

Comment: There's no code in the `make_filepath_variable()` function. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: this fuction was intended to set the location of an .mp3 file found in the .txt file to the variable "song"

Comment: Then shouldn't the call be inside the loop?

Comment: I've tried that and when it was in the loop it was still giving an undefined error, thats why I tried resorting to a global variable to solve the issue but it still would not work. Im currently working on adding the for line in fp portion.

Comment: it would probably be useful to define a `Song` class that holds all the metadata, instead of a dozen global variables.